# Trying to pass the cc_last4 and approval_code to my function? Help!

Tags: magento-1.7

Here is my code:

```
$getCcInfo = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->getLastItem();
    $order_data = $getCcInfo->getPayment()->getData('additional_information');

    foreach($order_data['authorize_cards'] as $key => $value){

        $transId        = $value['last_trans_id'];
        $ccCard         = $value['cc_last4'];
        $approvalCode   = $value['approval_code'];
    }
```

And here is where i want to pass these values:

```
$aWebOrder->CCHTransactionid = $transId;
$aPayment->CreditCardNumber  = $ccCard;
$aPayment->AuthorisationNumber = $approvalCode;
```

The first error i get is :

```
Undefined index: authorize_cards
```

and than these errors:

```
1. Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
2. Undefined variable: transId
3. Undefined variable: ccCard
4. Undefined variable: approvalCode
```

When i test these code on my magento root folder it gives me the results i want, it owrks just fine, but when i try to put it on my observer function and try to insert these values on db they get empty.

Any idea guys?

Comment: `Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->getLastItem()` is fatal, because it loads the complete collection! Set a limit! `getCollection()->setPageSize(1)->setOrder('created_at')->getFirstItem();`

Comment: I tried your code but my problem is still present :(

Comment: sure it is ;-) if I post a solution it will be an answer. I only told you to not implement bad performance killers.

Comment: Ahahaha... That was cool bro :-). I am still struggling with that, i don't understand why in my root folder when i test it it works just fine and it supposed to work on my function either.

Comment: what does `$order_data` contain?

Comment: $order_data contain authorize_cards array with all info like [last_trans_id],[processed_amount],[cc_type],[cc_last4] etc...

Comment: Which observer do you use?

Comment: @mageUz I am using <sales_order_place_after>. It looks like is saving the order after my block of code fires, because my code above reads when order is saved and placed on db. Just a though?

Comment: Use <checkout_submit_all_after>

Comment: What is the difference between these two events they look quite a same.

Comment: @mageUz i tried the <checkout_submit_all_after> event and same errors, i really don't understand now what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this logic with `checkout_submit_all_after` event and authorize.net payment method. See my code, maybe something is wrong in yours.
config.xml:

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <checkout_submit_all_after>
            <observers>
                <some_module>
                    <class>Some_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>checkoutSubmitAllAfter</method>
                </some_module>
            </observers>
        </checkout_submit_all_after>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Observer.php:

```
class Some_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function checkoutSubmitAllAfter($observer)
    {
        $order   = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $payment = $order->getPayment()->getData('additional_information');
        Mage::log($payment);
    }
}
```

systeml.log:

```
2013-10-31T18:53:06+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [authorize_cards] => Array
        (
            [b4aff98b4fc117cc74aa5314e26055f5] => Array
                (
                    [id] => b4aff98b4fc117cc74aa5314e26055f5
                    [requested_amount] => 
                    [balance_on_card] => 
                    [last_trans_id] => 2201013966
                    [processed_amount] => 1208.95
                    [cc_type] => VI
                    [cc_owner] => 
                    [cc_last4] => 0027
                    [cc_exp_month] => XX
                    [cc_exp_year] => XXXX
                    [cc_ss_issue] => 
                    [cc_ss_start_month] => 
                    [cc_ss_start_year] => 
                    [captured_amount] => 1208.95
                )

        )

)
```

This additional_information only stores if you use credit card processing payment methods (but not Saved CC). Maybe you are using another payment method.

Comment: You are genius, that was the trick. i had to pass this $payment = $order->getPayment()->getData('additional_information'); within my observer and change the event from checkout_onepage_controller_success_action to checkout_submit_all_after. thank you very much. This made my day :)